# Do you need to know wsdl for learning oracle service bus? is so what other languages do you need to know?

Tags: osb

Do you need to know wsdl for learning oracle service bus? Do you need to know wsdl for learning oracle service bus? is so what other languages do you need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know web services (wsdl), xml, xquery, xpath etc... + Java knowledge for customized codes and transports.

Comment: I think that with 'customized transports' he means, customized deployments for WebLogic Server. In WebLogic, you can create your own version of applications, of the ones who are delivered by standard. The coding is done in Java.